# Nginx Reverse Proxy very slow after enabling SSL

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx to do Reverse proxy, this is what I found

The nginx config:

```
# user  root;
worker_processes  2;
#daemon off;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

server {
      listen    9091 ssl;
      # ssl on;

      ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.key;

      location / {
                       proxy_pass https://reversed_endpoint.com ;
                       proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                       # proxy_buffering        off;
                   }

    }
}
```

What I found is like below:

```
dns_resolution: 0.006877, tcp_established: 0.007267, ssl_handshake_done: 0.068038, TTFB: 53.893920 Headersize: 1553 Responsesize: 4177
```

You can see the TTFB is so huge. Now, I found if I put this:

`listen    9091 ssl http2`;

TTFB becomes 0.5S, that is good, but I saw this

```
line=23","error_pos":"xxxxxx.model.lkml:23","fatal":true,"level":"fatal","login_required_oauth_application_id":null}],"drill_menu_build_time":0,"has_subtotals":false}}
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<waiting for 20S and then having below output>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
dns_resolution: 0.004799, tcp_established: 0.005162, ssl_handshake_done: 0.059099, TTFB: 0.059247 Headersize: 1454 Responsesize: 3402
```

You can see after data is received, it is still blocked, waited for almost 20 seconds, and then stopped and printed the status.

If I am not using nginx reverse proxy, everything is fast, no delay. the issue is I must use Nginx Reverse proxy with SSL enabled here.

I am not familiar with this Nginx config, can anyone help to answer this question? What should I do to make it faster under SSL?

Thanks